# Drush Installation - consolidation/site-process

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8, drush

I am looking to add Drush to my $PATH variable but when I try to globally require drush in Composer I get this error. (Basically saying that I shouldn't install consolidation/site-process. Cant seem to find any answers to this(.[Install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlZL.png)

Comment: Please read https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ thoroughly. `Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.` You don't install Drush globally anymore.

Comment: Thanks working fine locally now...